# Keyboard lighting and display switch control buttons (fn+f7,fn+f8) does not working(Asus ZenBook Pro 15, Ubuntu18.04)

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, asus

Having Asus ZenBook Pro 15(UX550GD) and installed Ubuntu 18.04. Everything is fine except the two function buttons(<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd>, <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f8</kbd>). The other function button combinations are working.

Comment: What they are supposed to do?

Comment: fn+f7: keyboard lighting, fn+f8: display switch

Comment: Quick guess: other keys supported by media key scancode, these two keys are supported by embedded controller and needs driver on windows.

Comment: Do you have an option to control keyboard backlit in Settings -> Power ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to hover the power icon and use the mouse wheel. This works with my old laptop with Xubuntu 18.04.

Comment: It does not work. :(